# How to list Windows shares from terminal?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, file-sharing

Here is a simple scenario I have:

1. Windows 7 is sharing a folder (D:\Projects).
2. Full Control permissions have been given to the folder.
3. In Ubuntu 10.10, I can see the Windows shares from Places -> Network menu.
4. I can create a folder in the shared Projects folder from Nautilus

How do I `ls` those same folders (displayed in Nautilus) from the terminal?
(`mount` and `ls /mnt` do not list those Windows shares)

Ps. Details on what I am doing:

1. Using Ubuntu as a "headless" VM using VirtualBox.
2. Accessing Ubuntu via PuTTY
3. Ability to give complete access to the Ubuntu VM for the Windows shared folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you've already used Nautilus to connect to the shares you're interested in, then the mounts for those shares are available in ~/.gvfs

So I've gone to my nautilus and typed smb://192.168.1.10/data into my location bar, which has mounted the share.  Then :

```
scaine@GroovyTosh:~/.gvfs$ ls -al
total 20
dr-x------  3 scaine scaine     0 2010-12-31 18:47 .
drwx------ 68 scaine scaine 20480 2010-12-31 19:42 ..
drwx------  1 scaine scaine     0 2010-10-05 19:57 data on 192.168.1.10
scaine@GroovyTosh:~/.gvfs$
```

If you need to list available shares, then as Danny says, you use smbclient.  In my case, I use "share" security model (not recommended!), so I don't need the -U parameter :

```
scaine@GroovyTosh:~/.gvfs$ smbclient -L 192.168.1.10
Enter scaine's password: 
Domain=[Mine] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.4]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    Data            Disk      Core Data
    Backups         Disk      Daily RSnapshot backups
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Core)
Domain=[Mine] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.4]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    CORE                 Core

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    Mine                 CORE
scaine@GroovyTosh:~/.gvfs$
```

Answer (score 3):

smbclient may be able to list the shares available on a windows machine, but not the machines.

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html

```
smbclient -L <windows-box> -U <username>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
smbclient -U windowsUserName%password -L windowsHost -W domainName
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows shares can also be accessed in the below way:

```
smbclient -L < Windows host name > -U < Windows Administrator account >
```